# Semantic UI in Chrome Extension: issue when displaying in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, semantic-ui

I'm currently working on a Chrome Extension and I'm using Semantic UI to build the interface. When the user activates the extension it will show a popup which is actually an iFrame. In this iFrame I have a table and I'd like this table to take the full width of the iFrame. The iFrame width is fixed (500px). The problem is because the iFrame is 600px the table is displayed as the device is 500px (makes sense since it's a responsive framework.

But I'd like to change this behavior and force the table to display as it would be on a desktop screen.

Today this is what I get

[image]
Now I'd like to obtain the following result (fake image :)

[image]

Here is the code of my iFrame

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
  <script src="js/ext/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ext/semantic-2.4.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/popup.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <div>
      <table class="ui celled padded collapsing table">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="single line">#</th>
            <th>Event mapping</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>
              1
            </td>
            <td class="single line">
              <div class="ui right action left icon input mini">
                <i class="search icon"></i>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Selector">
                <div class="ui basic floating dropdown button mini">
                  <div class="text">Identify</div>
                  <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
                  <div class="menu">
                    <div class="item">Page</div>
                    <div class="item">Track</div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td class="right aligned">

            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th colspan="5">
              <div class="ui left floated">
                <button id="btn-startcapture" class="positive ui button">Start capture</button>
              </div>
            </th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS style I apply to the iframe tag on the caller page

```
iframe.segmentizor-panel-iframe-toggle {
  left: calc(100% - 500px) !important;
}

iframe.segmentizor-panel-iframe {
    top: 0px;
    left: calc(100% + 10px);
    display: block;
    z-index: 2147483647;
    box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 7px 0px 12px 13px;
    position: fixed !important;
    width: 500px !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
    border-width: initial;
    border-style: none;
    border-color: initial;
    border-image: initial;
    transition: left 0.4s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}
```

Sorry if the question looks quite trivial. Still in the learning curve... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried editing the max-width css? Althought you may be setting the width to be 800px, if the max is only 600 it would only get to that.

Comment: Thanks Nick for taking the time I've updated my post I got confused with all the tests. Size of the iframe is 500px.

Answer (score 1):

First, remove the collapsing class

https://semantic-ui.com/collections/table.html#collapsing

> **Collapsing**
>
> A table can be collapsing, taking up only as much space as its rows.

Also, I think you could add some additional style inside the iframe's head section.

After

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
```

Add some style like you would on any page...

```
<style>
   table{
       width: 100%;
   }
</style>
```

Or you could add some classes, or other css styling for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your guidance I managed to do it by:

Adding the following class in my iFrame style

```
min-width: 800px !important;
```

Then in my iFrame page I added a new div with the size of the iFrame and used a width of 100% for the table

```
<div style="max-width: 450px">
    <table class="ui celled padded unstackable collapsing table" style="width:100%">
```